$\{(x,c)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}|f(x)>c\}$ is a subset of the interior of the hypograph of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.
I would like to ask if the following claim is correct?

Claim$\quad$ Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, then the interior of its hypograph $H_f=\{(x,c)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}|f(x)\geq c\}$ satisfies
$$
\{(x,c)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}|f(x)>c\} \subseteq \text{int}H_f.
$$

Here is my proof attempt:

Proof$\quad$ Suppose that $(y,d)\in\{(x,c)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}|f(x)>c\}$, where $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $d\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(y)>d$. Assume to the contrary that $(y,d)\notin\text{int}H_f$, that is, assume to the contrary that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $N_{\epsilon}(y,d)\bigcap\{(x,c)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}|f(x)<c\}\neq\emptyset$. Then there is a sequence $\{(y_n,d_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}$ such that, $(y_n,d_n)\to(y,d)$ as $n\to\infty$ and $f(y_n)<d_n$ for all $n$. Since $f$ is continuous, we must have $f(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=d$. However, this contradicts the fact that $f(y)>d$. Therefore, $(y,d)\in\text{int}H_f$. This completes the proof.

I am not sure if the claim is correct, and I am not sure if my proof of the claim is correct either. Could someone please help me check? Thank you so much in advance!

The claim is correct, and your proof is fine imho.

@daw Thank you very much!
